# Do we need to transition to Using MSAL with Yammer Group API endpoints for a Yammer network in Non-Native mode?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, yammer

In a recent announcement from Microsoft they are saying:

> Starting December 1 2020, Yammer Groups API endpoints  will only
> support the usage of Azure Active Directory (AAD) tokens.  Yammer
> Groups API endpoints will no longer support the usage of Yammer OAuth
> tokens. Microsoft recommends that customers and partners transition to
> using Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) and AAD tokens with the
> Yammer API.

Here is the [link to the announcement](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/yammer-blog/using-msal-with-yammer-groups-api/ba-p/1593907).

Does this apply to the Yammer network which is in Non-native Mode without Connected Yammer Groups? or this is only for the Native mode Yammer network?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the two passages：

> Starting December 1 2020, Yammer Groups API endpoints  will only
> support the usage of Azure Active Directory (AAD) tokens.  Yammer
> Groups API endpoints will no longer support the usage of Yammer OAuth
> tokens.

and

> In non-Native Yammer networks, users without Group creation rights in
> AAD will be able to create unconnected Yammer Groups.

It should apply to the Yammer network which is in Non-native Mode without Connected Yammer Groups.

Comment: I was thinking otherwise because of this line in the notes section "All Connected Yammer Groups (including Yammer networks in Native Mode) will require AAD tokens. Using the Yammer OAuth tokens will return a rejected response."

They are explicitly talking about connected Yammer Groups and Native mode but not mention about "Non-Native mode".

Comment: Also, this paragraph makes me think it doesn't apply to Non-Native mode. "As Yammer continues its journey to integrate into the Microsoft 365 ecosystem, there will be even more shared Yammer experiences across Microsoft 365, such as with Teams, Outlook and other applications. All of these require using AAD tokens. Yammer's OAuth token cannot be accepted to conduct these operations. Overtime all Yammer API endpoints will be changed to exclusively support AAD tokens."

What are your thoughts?